# Unpack an indexed object of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, unzip

I have an object (**prec_score**) that was derived from a "groupby" function of a dataframe.  The object has an index column(**source**), and an unnamed column of a 2-element tuple.

I would like to unpack/unzip the tuple into two separate columns "mean" and "precision."

*****Here's what I have***:**

```
prec_score = psi.groupby('source').apply(auc_group)

source
P03                     (0.0042910503473030034, 0.004975514927052615)
P04a                    (0.1722996231123154, 0.19441195500593225)
P04b                    (0.26313913996999294, 0.31874320468051276)
P04c                    (0.2612986898318525, 0.2541227790666698)
P04d                    (0.4529458009123246, 0.49560813661716663)
P04e                    (0.5467338804179422, 0.6847925038107519)
P06                     (0.003373416937568991, 0.007662479097491571)
P08                     (0.001412431535914154, 0.005282299334282409)
P09                     (0.011918926133313022, 0.00913808688008598)
P10                     (0.020750483361235646, 0.02767490357333552)
P11                     (0.06496517302643716, 0.049191221238955335)
P12                     (0.015587295242605693, 0.009555300604012188)
P13                     (0.04052937620271101, 0.03807649224213866)
P14                     (0.012883159363864815, 0.00843085863452591)
P15                     (0.006228328662793101, 0.006527283344563865)
dtype:object
```

**Here's what I want:**

```
source                          mean                precision
P03                     0.0042910503473030034   0.004975514927052615
P04a                    0.1722996231123154      0.19441195500593225
P04b                    0.26313913996999294     0.31874320468051276
P04c                    0.2612986898318525      0.2541227790666698
P04d                    0.4529458009123246      0.49560813661716663
P04e                    0.5467338804179422      0.6847925038107519
P06                     0.003373416937568991    0.007662479097491571
P08                     0.001412431535914154    0.005282299334282409
P09                     0.011918926133313022    0.00913808688008598
P10                     0.020750483361235646    0.02767490357333552
P11                     0.06496517302643716     0.049191221238955335
P12                     0.015587295242605693    0.009555300604012188
P13                     0.04052937620271101     0.03807649224213866
P14                     0.012883159363864815    0.00843085863452591
P15                     0.006228328662793101    0.006527283344563865
```

Comment: what is `psi` ?

Comment: @balderman psi was a dataframe

Comment: pandas df ? it makes sense to tag the question with pandas

Comment: @balderman, yes a pandas df and I will retag.  thanks.

Comment: @balderman, the reason I didn't include pandas dataframe because the object "prec_score,"  after I performed the "groupby,"  presented itself as an "object" type.  I executed "Print(prec_score.info)" and received "SERIES OBJECT HAS NO ATTRIBUTE 'TYPE' message

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
was using iloc improperly. This works

`df[['mean', 'precision']] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df[1], index=df.index)`

works with this df

`df=pd.DataFrame(data=[['P03',(0.0042910503473030034,0.004975514927052615)], ['P04a',(0.1722996231123154,0.19441195500593225)])`

Comment: p_score[['mean','precision']] = pd.DataFrame(p_score.iloc[[1]].tolist(), index=p_score.index)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 972, in __setitem__
    self._set_with_engine(key, value)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1005, in _set_with_engine
    loc = self.index._engine.get_loc(key) 
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

Comment: File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 75, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
TypeError: '['mean', 'precision']' is an invalid key
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-70-0cce53caf3b0>", line 1, in <module>
    p_score[['mean','precision']] = pd.DataFrame(p_score.iloc[[1]].tolist(), index=p_score.index)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 998, in __setitem__

Comment: self._set_with(key, value)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1035, in _set_with
    self.loc[key] = value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 688, in __setitem__
    indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 636, in _get_setitem_indexer
    return self._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=0, is_setter=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",

Comment: File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1212, in _convert_to_indexer
    return self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis, raise_missing=True)[1]

Comment: wasn't supposed to use iloc. It's fixed